# Dialog on Exit - onResume is not called

Tags: android

Currently I am working on a application, which contains one switch. When we touch switch , it initiates a Dialog.

I want to know:

1. Since My Dialog box is above Activity, when we exit from dialog why `onResume` us not called.
2. Which functions get called when Dialog ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement the `onCancelled()` and `onDismiss()` listeners for the `Dialog`. These will be called when the user either cancels, or dismisses the dialog.

The reason `onResume()` is never called, is because the activity is never paused. Its just an overlay, and your activity carries on in the background.

Comment: Hi Mimminito, Thanks for a quick response. one more query , Can we call , OnResume from onDismiss(). As in my code there is some code in onResume, which should be called when Dialog ends.

Comment: No you cannot. You can move your code into another method, and call this when the dialog is closed/dismissed. Or you can create your own listener interface, call that from the dialog, and then call your code when your listener receives a callback

Comment: DO NOT try and mess with the Android lifecycle methods. If there are pieces of code you need to run when certain events happen, extract them into other methods